# Permission issue with spark yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have an spark 1.5.1 process installed on a HDP 2.1 cluster. Which uses hadoop 2.4.0, and I'm having permission denied issues when the driver tries to write into a given Hive table.

The user submiting the job is gvp_service, and during the job it's workers are able to write with gvp_service permission, but when interacting with the metastore I receive the following exception:

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/apps/hive/warehouse/gbic_video_video.db/gbic_video_video_raw_users/global_op_id=1000/service_type=1/day=2015-09-15":gvp_service:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:265)

Why is it using yarn user for this task? Is it due to use Hadoop client 2.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the job is submitted as which user? To interact with hive you should have "hive-site.xml" in $SPARK_INSTALL_DIR/conf with below contents

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <!-- Ensure that the following statement points to the Hive Metastore URI in your cluster -->
  <value>thrift://<METASTORE IP>:9083</value>
  <description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps